# git apply : error trailing whitespace

Tags: git, patch

Lately, I've been playing a little bit with git. I'm trying to simulate to apply a patch to my master branch, this patch comprehends a commit where I added some comments to a java operation. I generated the patch using git `format-patch`. Then I switched to my master branch to apply the patch.
the following errors occurred when executing the git apply command :

```
path/to/my/patch/file: line x
path/to/my/patch/file: line x+1
path/to/my/patch/file: line x+2
path/to/my/patch/file: line x+3
```

I note that I also tried  the following arguments : `--ignore-space`, `ignore-whitespace`,

Comment: What's the exact error message? `path/to/my/patch/file: line x` does not look like one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are not concerned with applying trailing whitespaces to your repo you can use the flag `--whitespace=fix` to ignore the error and apply anyway

```
git apply --whitespace=fix your.patch
```

I have heard some people say that the default is to warn and apply the patch, but that has not been my experience and the above solution seems to do what I want.